# "CONCAT"enated column not showing up in database table

Tags: mysql

I tried concat function to combine two columns, i got the output also but 
my question is why i don't see new column being added to the table. Is concatenating is just a temporary result?

```
  SELECT CONCAT(Name,',',Continent)AS new_address FROM Country
```

Comment: `SELECT` just returns information from the DB, it doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this creates a column that only exists in your `SELECT` query.

It certainly does not alter the underlying table.

If you wanted to add this computation to the underlying table you could add a [generated column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) as of MySQL 5.7.6.

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Continent VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Country 
VALUES ('France', 'Europe'), 
       ('Nigeria','Africa');

ALTER TABLE Country
ADD new_address VARCHAR(201) AS (CONCAT(Name,',',Continent));

SELECT *
FROM Country;
```

[Online Demo](http://rextester.com/ZZA63490)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column to the table, you need to alter the table:

```
alter table country add new_address varchar(255);
```

Then you can set the value using `update`:

```
update country
    set new_address = concat_ws(' ', name, continent);
```

I prefer `concat_ws()` for this type of operation because it does not return `NULL` if one of the columns is `NULL`.

Note:  The table has the "correct" values after the update.  But, subsequent changes to the table might require that you re-run the update or that you use a trigger to maintain consistency.

On best practice is to define a view to do the calculation:

```
create view v_country as
    select c.*, concat_ws(' ', name, continent) as new_address
    from country;
```

When you access the data through the view, the `new_address` field will always be correct.

Comment: There's no need for new manually populated columns or views if they are on a version that supports generated columns.

Comment: @Nag . . . Just to clarify Martin's comment, generated columns are available in version 5.7.6.  You can read more about them at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html.  These would be the way to go if you are using a more recent version of MySQL.